# Onclick event on an array of list items

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, onclick, getelementsbytagname

I have a list and I want to create a function that will bold the clicked list item. So far I managed to create a function and assign it to list items. Onclick, it bolds, but just one item. I don't know how to set it for each item.

I could have used id to bold the items but there will be a lot of items in the list. I can't deal with each one of them.

**html**

```
<ul>
    <li>apple</li>
    <li>orange</li>
    <li>banana</li>
</ul>
```

**javascript**

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

function markSelection() {
    if(list[0].style.fontWeight !== "bold") {
        list[0].style.fontWeight = "bold";
    } else {
        list[0].style.fontWeight = "normal";
    }
}

for (i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; i++){
    list[i].onclick = markSelection;
}
```

It bolds only list[0]. How can I set it to bold the clicked list item?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/by9bP/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function markSelection() {
    if(this.style.fontWeight !== "bold") {
        this.style.fontWeight = "bold";
    } else {
        this.style.fontWeight = "normal";
    }
}

for (i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; i++){
    list[i].onclick = markSelection;
}
```

Comment: Haha. I knew I could use `this` but couldn't get it to work. Thank you. I'll stick with `this` instead of `evt.target` for now.

Comment: @akinuri, thanks, but then why did you accept the answer suggesting using `event.target`...? :)

Comment: Well, he was first to answer and he also linked a demo. I saw yours after I saw his reply. Let's not forget you got 46k~ :P but but, since I'm new here and new to js I don't know which answer is "better". Should I change it? o.O

Comment: @akinuri, you should accept the answer helped you the most. It doesn't matter who has more reputation.(and believe me that 15 points or even 150 don't effect in the long run, I was just curious why did you accept the answer you decided not to use.) the other answer is fine, you can keep it checked.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the context of the click event like this.

```
function markSelection(evt) {
    var tar = evt.target;
    if(tar.style.fontWeight !== "bold")
        tar.style.fontWeight = "bold";
    else
        tar.style.fontWeight = "normal";
}
```

See fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/achrome/uwjkT/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's working now. I'm not familiar with evt.target. Gonna look it up.

Comment: Care to answer another question? On the second item click, I want list items to switch back to normal. I mean I don't want to have two or more bolded item. Just 1.

Comment: Put a loop in your condition which switches the whole list back to normal, and then bolden the target.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a class and toggle it whenever you want ( for example adding it on click, and let css handle the style )

http://jsfiddle.net/blackjim/by9bP/2/

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

function markSelection() {

    if(this.className.indexOf('boldFruit')===-1){
        this.className += " boldFruit";
    }
}

for (i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; i++){
    list[i].onclick = markSelection;
}
```

CSS

```
li {
    font-size: 20px;
}

li.boldFruit {
    font-weight: bold;  
}
```

Comment: Extra code. I want to toggle between bold and normal onclick. Then again, thanks for the reply.

Comment: It's not extra code, it's almost the same. But it's the proper way, you should handle style with CSS if you want to have your code maintainable. Maybe you will need to add something later to that class for example, then you'll see why it was the proper way. You choose.

Comment: I get your point. In fact I'm alreay using this on another element. I just didn't want to create two classes just to modify a single property.